# Sitecore: Installing one language Package is causing the already existing language to be deleted

Tags: package, sitecore, locale

We have content in various languages in **Sitecore**. I am trying to take a package of one of the languages in **Sitecore** by the option `Items Dynamically` and using the language filter and selecting the language whose data need to be packaged.

However on installing the package we see that versions for existing languages are deleted and we see version of only the new language from the new package installed.

Please let me on how to retain existing language upon installation of new package.

Answer (score 1):

Select "Merge -> Clear" under "Installation Options". If you chose "Overwrite" (which I presume you do, from your description) - the target (including all language versions) will get replaced with the item from your package.

See page 29-30 in the Package Designer Administrators Guide.

- http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Package%20Designer%20Administrator%20Guide.aspx
- http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/package_designer_admin_guide-a4.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The package though taken only for a particular locale when I choose the suggested "Merge -> Clear" it also clears the version on other locales I am also stuck with the same problem. I tried the Append version it works fine, however if there is a version being removed for a particular locale then this does not reflect (this makes sense as append only places newer versions and no delete them). Please note that the package i have taken is done currently and taken only for one locale

@Mark- could you please look at this as well and provide inputs